# Show that $e^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $e^{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational. My approach:
$$
e^{\sqrt 2}+e^{-\sqrt 2}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{(2k)!}=:2s
$$
Define $s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2^k}{(2k)!}$, then:
$$
s-s_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{(2k)!}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{\prod_{k=1}^{2k}(2n+2+k)}\\<\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{(2n+3)^{2k}}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\frac{(2n+3)^2}{(2n+3)^2-2}
$$
Now assume $s=\frac{p}{q}$ for $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$. This implies:
$$
0<\frac{p}{q}-s_n<\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\frac{(2n+3)^2}{(2n+3)^2-2}\iff\\
0<p\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}-qs_n\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}<\frac{2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\frac{(2n+3)^2}{(2n+3)^2-2}
$$
But $\left(p\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}-qs_n\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}\right)\in\mathbb{N}$ which is a contradiction for large $n$. Thus $s$ is irrational. Can we somehow use this to prove $e^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since the sum of two rational numbers is rational, one or both of $e^{\sqrt{2}}$
and $e^{-\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational. But, $e^{-\sqrt{2}}=1/e^{\sqrt{2}}$,
and hence both are irrational.

Comment: Uhhh, so close! Thanks for the answer, +1

Comment: You did all the hard work :-)

Comment: Nice. Here is an easier one :If A,B,C are rational and $Ae^2 +Be+C=0$ then A=B=C=0.

Comment: Why can't both numbers be rational?

Comment: @DVD: OP proves it in his post

Answer (score 11):

$e^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental because of [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem):

> If $a\neq 0$ is algebraic, then $e^a$ is transcendental.

It is written in the [list of transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental).

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $e^{\pm\sqrt{n}}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, it is enough to exploit the [Gauss' continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction) for $\tanh$ and [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction) about the periodicity of continued fractions of quadratic irrationals.
 A detailed explanation of this approach (for $n=2$) is outlined in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1945002/44121).

Comment: you might want to look at this method http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864678/are-there-any-natural-proofs-of-irrationality-using-the-decimal-characterization/1864796#1864796 here $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(2k)!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b_n}$ where $b_1 = 2,  b_{n+1} = b_n \frac{n (n+1)}{2}$, and the same proof applies. But I'm not sure how to modify it for $e^{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: @user1952009: to exploit some Taylor expansion is another way for providing tight rational approximations of such numbers (then prove their irrationality) but I somewhat prefer the CF approach since it gives more manageable and more accurate approximations.