# A continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}\Bigg({e^\sqrt{2}-1 \above 1.5pt e^\sqrt{2}+1 }\Bigg)$

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, oeis

This question is about the integer sequence [A123168](https://oeis.org/A123168). The title of the sequence reads: Continued fraction for - $$\sqrt{2}\Bigg({e^\sqrt{2}-1 \above 1.5pt e^\sqrt{2}+1 }\Bigg)$$ A comment claims that 'this continued fraction shows that $e^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational". I thought Lindemann & Weierstrass theorem established the irrationality of $e^\sqrt{2}$ so what is the motivation behind this particular continued fraction and the irrationality of $e^\sqrt{2}$? How do you write that continued fraction out?

***note***: I am not asking for a proof of the irrationality of $e^\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: "How do you write that continued fraction out?" : $[0;0, 1, 6, 5, 14, 9, 22, 13, 30, 17, 38, 21, 46,...$

Comment: ^ sure but I meant explicitly using fraction notation.

Comment: Well, you know, $[a; b, c, d, ...]$ means $a+1/(b+1/(c+1/(d+...))) $.

Comment: Not quite sure but  $$0 + \cfrac{1}{0
          + \cfrac{1}{6
          + \cfrac{1}{5+ \cfrac{1}{14 + \cdots}}}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [Gauss' continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction),
$$ \tanh(x)=\cfrac{x}{1+\cfrac{x^2}{3+\cfrac{x^2}{5+\cfrac{x^2}{7+\ldots}}}}\tag{1}$$
hence by evaluating at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$,
$$ \sqrt{2}\tanh\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\color{green}{\sqrt{2}\,\frac{e^{\sqrt{2}}-1}{e^{\sqrt{2}}+1}} = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1/2}{3+\cfrac{1/2}{5+\cfrac{1/2}{7+\ldots}}}}\tag{2}$$
and by converting the RHS of $(2)$ into an ordinary continued fraction,
$$ \color{green}{\sqrt{2}\,\frac{e^{\sqrt{2}}-1}{e^{\sqrt{2}}+1}} = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{14+\ldots}}}}=\color{green}{[0;1,6,5,14,9,22,13,30,\ldots]}\tag{3}$$
proving that the LHS of $(3)$ is an irrational number (since the continued fraction has an infinite number of terms) and not an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $2$ (otherwise, by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction), the continued fraction would be periodic from some point on). Assuming that $e^{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$, we have that the LHS of $(3)$ is a rational multiple of $\sqrt{2}$, hence an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degre $2$. We have already proved that is not our case, hence
$$ (3)\implies \color{red}{e^{\sqrt{2}}\not\in\mathbb{Q}}.\tag{4} $$

Comment: Although a closed formula is given in the description in the sequence - I believe I have one also. That was my motivation for the question.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: in a explicit way, the $n$-th term of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2},\frac{e^{\sqrt{2}}-1}{e^{\sqrt{2}}+1}$ is $2n-1$ if $n$ is odd and $4n-2$ if $n$ is even. I am assuming the zeroth term is $0$.

Comment: I write $s_n ={n(n-1)(n+3) \above 1.5 pt 2}$ and $t_n = {n+1 \choose 2}$. We can interpret $s_n$ as the sum of sets of the form $\{2,3\}$, $\{5,6,7\}$, $\{9,10,11,12\}$, and so on. Surely $t_n$ are the so called "triangular numbers". I write $a_n =(s_n,t_n)$ the greatest common divisor of $s_n$ and $t_n$. Then for odd $n$  we have that $a_n =$[A123168](https://oeis.org/A123168)

Comment: Perhaps this continued fraction is algebraic of degree ${} > 2$, but more likely it is transcendental.

Comment: @GEdgar: while it is true that $(3)$ is a trascendental number, to prove it from $(3)$ does not strike me as an easy task. I am not sure it is possible, either.

Comment: I just mean that, in your explanation, do not say it is an algebraic number with degree ${} > 2$, instead say it is not an algebraic number with degree $2$.

Comment: @GEdgar: oh, thanks, I misunderstood you. You are right, proof fixed.