# Proving that: $9.9998\lt \frac{\pi^9}{e^8}\lt 10$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, approximation, approximation-theory, transcendental-numbers

I would like to use mathematical tools to prove that 
    $$9.9998\lt \frac{\pi^9}{e^8}\lt 10$$

With an on-line calculator I got

$$  \frac{\pi^9}{e^8}\approx 9.9998387978$$
But I do not know any good way to prove this. I failed to use Taylor expansion 
$$e^8 =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{8^n}{n!}$$

Any idea?

Comment: Well, it looks like taking natural logs helps.  You want $\ln(9.9998)<9\ln (\pi)-8<\ln (10)$.  Still numerical.

Comment: It's looks nicer to proof $\,2980909<100 \cdot \pi^9<2980910\,$  and   $\,298095<100 \cdot e^8<298096\,$ . :-)

Comment: That's funny. How did you discover such inequality?

Comment: A natural question might be the following: can you show two rational numbers $r,s$ such that there are no integers $i,k,j$ such that $r^i \sim 10^k s^j$?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: how is that possible, if $\mathbb{Z}\log(r)+\mathbb{Z}\log(s)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: But than this inequality was expected! We couldn't know that $i=9, j=8, k=1$, but such numbers had to exist.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: of course, I get your point, there is nothing really *special* here, but I still find such kind of numerical coincidences amusing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please here is another one. I found your answer here clear and direct. But for this I haven,t found a satisfactory answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482717/how-to-prove-19-999e-pi-pi20?rq=1

Comment: @GuyFsone: nbubis' answer to the linked question has a structure that is similar to my answer here. The point is that the constant $e^{\pi}$ appears in the context of j-invariants and modular forms, hence it can be computed through fast-convergent numerical algorithms, recalling the AGM mean for the computation of complete elliptic integrals of the first kind. nbubis' answer is *very* satisfactory by my point of view, but I will take some time to think about an alternative approach. I am not sure to be able to do better.

Comment: Thanks in advance.  I am not so familiar with the notion of "j-invariants and modular forms" :) that is why I got lost at some point.

Comment: Guy:  Please stop making very trivial edits to get you post bumped to the front page.  This example here, among many others: indicate very inappropriate behavior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My approach can be summarized as follows:

1. By a [well-known fact about Euler numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas), $\pi^9$ is given by a rational multiple of the fast-converging series $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^9}$;
2. By [the generalized continued fraction for the hyperbolic cotangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1945002/44121) function, it is pretty simple to produce accurate rational approximations of $e^8$;
3. The given inequality can be proved by producing accurate rational approximations for both $\pi^9$ and $e^8$ through the previous points, then by comparing them.

---

1. $$\pi^9 = \frac{203325460470370265464832}{6820919298826171875}\pm 7\cdot 10^{-5} $$
2. $$ e^8 = \frac{6456755}{2166}\pm 4\cdot 10^{-8}$$
3. Done.

Comment: Amazing! $(+1)^\infty$

Comment: I wish everything was as simple as "1,2,3,done" for me (like it is for you). +1

Comment: @hypergeometric: $+500>(+1)^\infty$. One can do it by `start a bounty`.

Comment: Any idea here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643216/prove-that-7-frac5-phi-e-pi-7-0000689-where-phi-is-the-golden-ratio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Jack can one we give a bounty on a solved question?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh see here too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643216/prove-that-7-frac5-phi-e-pi-7-0000689-where-phi-is-the-golden-ratio?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @GuyFsone: it is possible to offer a bounty for an already answered question, yes.