# Possible Pythagorean relation with Golden Ratio $ \phi^2+e^2 \approx \pi^2$

Tags: soft-question, approximation, approximation-theory, golden-ratio, constants

While study Numerics and playing with famous constants ($e$, $\pi$, Golden ratio) I came across the following relation

$$ \color{blue}{1.6^2+2.7^2 = 9.85\approx 3.14^2}$$

This is nothing special but patently, by first oder approximation one glimpses that,

$$ e \approx 2.7,~~~~~~\phi\approx1.6~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~\pi\approx3.14$$
where $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the well known **Golden ratio**. Putting this in the previous relation we get

$$ \color{blue}{\phi^2+e^2 \approx \pi^2}.$$

Although it is hopeless to get the perfect relation $ \color{blue}{\phi^2+e^2 =\pi^2},$ which could be an amazing **Pythagorean relation** between famous constants $\color{red}{e,\phi} $ and $\color{red}{\pi}$.
I believe there is a chance that there exists a 
**well know constant $\color{red}{\delta}$** (of this kind) such that we have the following approximation.

$$ \color{blue}{\phi^2+e^2 +\delta^2\approx \pi^2}.\tag{I}\label{Eq}$$
Which is also a **Pythagorean relation in three dimension.**

But since $ \color{blue}{\phi^2+e^2 >\pi^2}$, the best idea to find such constant is obviously to consider $\delta $ satisfying the relation.

$$\color{red}{\pm i\delta= \sqrt{\phi^2+e^2-\pi^2}\approx 0.37079062365 }$$

> **My Question**: 
>   Which Well known constant could be suitable in other to improve  this Pythagorean relation in $\eqref{Eq}$?

I am thankful to all your propositions. Please I would like if it is possible some very close approximation like here, 
[Proving that: $9.9998\lt \frac{\pi^9}{e^8}\lt 10$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489369/how-to-show-this-inequality-9-9998-lt-frac-pi9e8-lt-10)
or here 
[How to prove that: $19.999<e^\pi-\pi<20$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482717/how-to-prove-19-999e-pi-pi20)

Comment: Why did you take $e$ and $\phi$ to two significant digits but $\pi$ to three ?

Comment: Why should we assume there's anything special about $\delta$? We can easily come up with many relations like $\varphi^2+e^2\approx \pi^2$. I don't see any reason to assume that there's anything very deep here apart from that the numbers happen to be quite close together. Furthermore, what are you *really* asking? For us to find whether $\delta$ appears anywhere else or whether it's got a different closed for? I think either case is quite unlikely.

Comment: If you'd like to find constants close to  $\delta\approx0.37$, you could try this list of mathematical constants (http://bit.ly/2yPS2Db) and pick one such as Artin's constant (http://bit.ly/2iG683B) or $\frac1e$ or the median of the Gumbel distribution, $-\ln\ln2$ (http://bit.ly/2iG683B), which are all equal to $0.37\pm0.01$.

Comment: Please note that after all the goal is to improve the Pythagorean relation in (I). choosing a suitable delta which for sure a pure complex number .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108510/approximation-of-e-using-pi-and-phi?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a similar approach to the other question,

1. $\phi^2=\phi+1 = [2;1,1,1,\ldots]$ has simple convergents;
2. $e^2=[7; 2, 1, 1, 3, 18, 5, 1, 1, 6, 30, 8, 1, 1,\ldots]$ has simple convergents too;
3. $\pi^2$ is related to [the solution of the Basel problem through creative telescoping](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617710/44121):
   $$\pi^2 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{18}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}} $$
   and the last series is pretty fast-convergent.
4. It follows that
   $$ \phi^2=\frac{1597}{610}\pm 2\cdot 10^{-6} $$
   $$ e^2 = \frac{12288}{1663}\pm 2\cdot 10^{-7}$$
   $$ \pi^2 = \frac{16929464521}{1715313600}\pm 2\cdot 10^{-6}$$
   hence $\phi^2+e^2$ is very close to $10$, which on its turn is not very far from $\pi^2$ ($\pi\approx\sqrt{10}$ was already known to Babylonians). According to the inverse symbolic calculator we have

   $$ \phi^2+ e^2 \approx \pi^2+\delta^2 $$ with $$ \delta = G\left[\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)\right] $$ and $G$ being Catalan's constant.

Comment: For instant somebody proposed to tried $\delta =e^{-1}$ which is a good approximation so far. If you have anything in this direction it will be great.

Comment: @GuyFsone: a quick look at the inverse symbolic calculator (https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc) returns $$ \phi^2+ e^2 \approx \pi^2+\delta^2 $$ with $$ \delta = G\left[\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{12}\right)\right] $$ and $G$ being Catalan's constant.

Comment: It seems I cannot access that link could you tries with this equation $\phi^2+ e^2+\delta^2 \approx \pi^2$ which exactly the approximation I want. The other way was my attempt. I have tried your link but Cannot access to it from here.  thanks very much

Comment: @GuyFsone: as already remarked by other users, there is no way an approximate identity like $\phi^2+e^2+\delta^2\approx \pi^2$ might hold, since $\phi^2+e^2\approx 10$ is already greater than $\pi^2$. What you really want is $\phi^2+e^2\approx \pi^2+\delta^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$\delta = \sqrt{e^2 + \phi^2 - \pi^2}$ is presumably a transcendental number (though AFAIK there's no proof that it isn't rational). A good rational approximation of it is $33/89$.  I don't know if you'd call that a "well known constant".

Comment: @GuyFsone, Euler-Mascheroni...

Comment: @GuyFsone. In **very** contemporary mathematics, $33/89$ is known as RI constant and $848/2287$ as CL constant. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

I also once played with these famous constants- I came across to this following relation :

$e+\pi \cong 3\phi+1$ or $\phi\approx\frac{e+\pi-1}{3}$

Approximation error:$|3\phi-(e+\pi-1)|\approx0,00577 < \frac{3}{500}$

Being in Pythagorean relations- let's check for $e+\pi \cong 3\phi+1$ squaring the sides :

*Left side*:$(e+\pi)^2 =e^2+2(e+\pi)+\pi^2 $

*Right side*:$(3\phi+1)^2 =9\phi^2+2(3\phi+1)+1 $

Hense:

$e^2+\pi^2+2(e+\pi)\cong9\phi^2+2(3\phi+1)+1 $

$e^2+\pi^2\cong9\phi^2+1 $

The approximation error of: $\sqrt{|e^2+\pi^2-(9\phi^2+1)|} \approx e$