# Proving that $ 7<\frac{5\phi e}{\pi}< 7.0000689$ where $\phi$ is the Golden Ratio

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods, approximation, transcendental-numbers

In my numerics I need to show the following approximation:

$$ 7<\frac{5\phi e}{\pi}< 7.000069,$$

where $\phi = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the Golden Ratio and $e$ is the Euler's constant as well.

> Using an online calculator I got
>   $$\color{red}{\frac{5\phi e}{\pi}\approx 7.000068914.}$$

I have tried using the Taylor series

$$ e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!},$$

But This is not enough to  approximate accurately  the whole term.

> Does anyone have an idea to approximate $\frac{5\phi e}{\pi}$ ? Some other methods have been used here [How to prove that: $19.999<e^\pi-\pi<20$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482717/how-to-prove-that-19-999e-pi-pi20) and here [Proving that: $9.9998\lt \frac{\pi^9}{e^8}\lt 10$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489369/show-that-9-9998-lt-frac-pi9e8-lt-10)

Comment: In all seriousness: what's wrong with using a calculator to show this? You don't trust it or is this meant as a challenge on how to establish this inequality in a fancy way?

Comment: @Winther see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482717/how-to-prove-that-19-999e-pi-pi20 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489369/show-that-9-9998-lt-frac-pi9e8-lt-10

Comment: @YvesDaoust like here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489369/show-that-9-9998-lt-frac-pi9e8-lt-10 or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482717/how-to-prove-that-19-999e-pi-pi20

Comment: Ok, that was a complicated way of saying "the latter option". IMO there is almost zero chance there is a "nice / stylish / beautiful" way of doing this so your best approach is approximating the numbers involved and multiplying them (ala Jack's answer in the linked question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mimicking the approach shown in the mentioned question, both the continued fractions of $\phi$ and $e$ are simple and well-known. About $\frac{1}{\pi}$, one may use [Ramanujan's fast convergent series](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/ramanujan.html) to get
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\approx \frac{13562078735077}{30127364780832 \sqrt{2}}$$
with a relative error which is less than $3\cdot 10^{-8}$. Since
 $e\approx\frac{23225}{8544}$ with a relative error which is less than $3\cdot 10^{-9}$ and $\phi\approx \frac{4181}{2584}$ with a relative error which is less than $5\cdot 10^{-8}$, we have
$$ \frac{5\phi e}{\pi}\approx7+\frac{1}{14690}$$
with a relative error which is less than $10^{-7}$, proving the claim.

Answer (score 3):

**Part 1:** $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Archimedes obtains: $ \frac{223}{71} < \pi<\frac{22}{7}$
Hence: $ \frac{7}{22} <\frac{1}{\pi}<\frac{71}{223}$
We'll also use a trick: $\pi\approx 3\to\frac{1}{\pi}\approx\frac{7}{21}$

**Part 2:** $\phi$

$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 1.618$

*[The golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)* is connected to the *[Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)*: 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89…

And notably: $\phi=\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$

Here they are the first approximations:$\frac{2}{1};\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{3};\frac{8}{5};\frac{13}{8};\frac{21}{13};\frac{34}{21};\frac{55}{34};\frac{89}{55}...$

We'll consider the intervals of: $\frac{21}{13}<\phi<\frac{34}{21}$ and $\frac{55}{34}<\phi<\frac{89}{55}$

**Part 3:** Euler’s constant

As: $e=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...$

$e=2.5+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{120}+\frac{1}{720}+...$

OK, $e$ is bigger than 2.6 (because 1/6 is evident  bigger than 1/10) :

$2.6=\frac{26}{10}=\frac{13}{5}$

Euler’s number is also smaller than 2.72 (no proof ; and 2.75 is „too” big):

$2.72=2\frac{72}{100}=2\frac{18}{25}=\frac{68}{25}$

**Finally**

$5\phi\frac{1}{\pi}e$ :

*-Lower part*:
Version 1 (with the trick):  $5*\frac{21}{13}*\frac{7}{21}*\frac{13}{5}=7 $

Version 2:  $5*\frac{55}{34}*\frac{7}{22}*\frac{68}{25}=5*\frac{5*11}{34}*\frac{7}{2*11}*\frac{2*34}{5*5}=7 $

*-Biggest part*:
Our **convergence will be slow** – we reduce into three tries:

First try:
$5*\frac{34}{21}*\frac{7}{22}*\frac{68}{25}=5*\frac{34}{3*7}*\frac{7}{2*11}*\frac{2*34}{5*5}=\frac{34^2}{3*5*11}=\frac{1156}{165}=7.00(60)\approx 7.0061 $

Second try: $5*\frac{55}{34}*\frac{71}{223}*\frac{68}{25}=\frac{2*11*71}{223}\approx 7.0045 $

Third try: $5*\frac{89}{55}*\frac{7}{22}*\frac{68}{25}=\frac{7*34*89}{(5*11)^2}\approx 7.0023 $

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is simply $(1 + \sqrt 5)/2$. Square roots are easily approximable using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

For $\pi$ you have [lots and lots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#20th_and_21st_centuries) of [very fast algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Miscellaneous_approximations).